ERROR: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected - Oracle JOIN SQL
I'm currently working on an Oracle query; I want to grab the first 10 rows using an INNER JOIN on 2 tables. However, I keep getting an error

ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Any ideas how to fix this error?
SELECT inc.ASSIGNED_TO, inc.OPENED_AT, u.NAME 
FROM INCIDENT AS inc 
INNER JOIN USER AS u ON inc.ASSIGNED_TO = u.USER_ID
ORDER BY inc.OPENED_AT DESC 
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY;

I'm getting this error:

ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 14 Column: 213


You are not showing complete code. The Error is at line 14 and we see just 5 lines of your code. Please provide complete code.

Could USER be a reserved word? it is syntax highlighted; use double-quotes around USER like "USER"

Yes, this is correct. USER is a reserved word. Is your table really called USER? Then you need parentheses: INNER JOIN "USER".

See fiddle for working code.

While in standard SQL the AS for table aliases is optional, Oracle doesn't allow it, unfortunately. Hence:
SELECT inc.assigned_to, inc.opened_at, u.name 
FROM incident inc 
INNER JOIN user u ON inc.assigned_to = u.user_id
ORDER BY inc.opened_at DESC 
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY;


USER is a reserved word for Oracle SQL; see https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Oracle-SQL-Reserved-Words.html
Use double-quotes around USER like "USER"
